# Getting a "Future Warning" when importing for Yahoo with Pandas-Datareader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am currently , successfully, importing stock information from Yahoo using pandas-datareader. However, before the extracted data, I always get the following message:

> FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.

Would anyone have an idea of what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: I think nothing you can do, it depends on pandas-datareader library. Until creators of this library eventually will update it's code to up to date Pandas api.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** The cause of this warning is that, basically, the `pandas_datareader` is importing a module from the `pandas` library that will be deprecated. Specifically, it is importing `pandas.util.testing` whereas the new preferred module will be `pandas.testing`.

**Solution:** First off this is a warning, and not an outright error, so it won't necessarily break your program. So depending on your exact use case, you may be able to ignore it for now.

That being said, there are a few options you can consider:

- *Option 1: Change the code yourself* -- Go into the `pandas_datareader` module and modify the line of code in `compat_init.py` that currently says `from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal` simply to `from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal`. This will import the same function from the correct module.
- *Option 2: Wait for `pandas-datareader` to update* --You can also wait for the library to be upgraded to import correctly and then run `pip3 install --upgrade pandas-datareader`. You can go to the Github repo for `pandas-datareader` and raise an issue.
- *Option 3: Ignore it* -- Just ignore the warning for now since it doesn't break your program.

Answer (score -1):

You may find the 'util.testing' code in pandas_datareader, which is separate from pandas.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this `from pandas_datareader import data` import it has deprecated.

Replace it with:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
```

or

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

Because many functions from the data module have been included in the top level API.

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978137/11301900) ?

Answer (score -1):

in your virtual environment, simply change the import statement in

```
/env/lib/site-packages/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py
```

*(or the site-packages directory for python if you are not using a virtual environment)*


from

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

to

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034041/11301900) ?

Answer (score -2):

Try below line to import, it will work.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

For more information find the below link.

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/fel32c/getting_a_future_warning_error_on_a_simple_web/

Comment: This doent sole the issue, and why would it. It is't any different than what the OP wrote

Answer (score -2):

For mac OS open `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py`

change: `from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal`

to: `from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal`

Comment: Isn't modifying the library's code like this a bad idea?

Comment: @AMC: It depends. In this case, the warning comes from a message that the pandas `util.testing` module is deprecated, and to favor `pandas.testing` instead. Until `pandas_datareader` switches their import to the correct module, you can get around this warning just by manually editing the package yourself to comply with the new way of importing the testing function `assert_frame_equal`.

Comment: @CarlS My comment was referring to the idea in general, not the specifics of this particular situation.