# trying to import pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, conda, pandas-datareader

i am new in coding. i was trying to import pandas_datareader and this appeared on the cell of jupyter Notebook(anaconda)  C:\Users\ROLAND\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\compat__init__.py:7: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [Getting a “Future Warning” when importing for Yahoo with Pandas-Datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60039161/getting-a-future-warning-when-importing-for-yahoo-with-pandas-datareader). Can you share some information on your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of pandas_datareader:

```
import pandas_datareader
pandas_datareader.__version__
```

Currently the latest version is '0.8.1'. Via

```
conda update pandas_datareader -c delichon
```

you will at least get version 0.7.0. If this doesn't fix the warning, you can use pip to install from pypi

```
pip install pandas_datareader
```

However, it's not recommended to mix conda and pip  installs in the base environment, so create a separate one for your project.